# How to use a % after %s in python?

Tags: python, string

My problem boils down to:

```
# examplecode
# i want to achieve the string "1.1%"

s = '%s%' % '1.1'
# but this throws me a
ValueError: incomplete format
```

ofc i could just use `format()`

```
s = '{}%'.format('1.1')
```

but is there a way to use a `%` after a `%s` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape `%` with another `%`, like this

```
>>> s = '%s%%' % '1.1'
>>> s
'1.1%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just double the %.

```
s = '%s%%' % '1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Double the %, `"%s%%" % 10` should give you `10%`.